# Nesting Asynchronous Promises in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous, promise

I have a situation where I need to perform dependent asynchronous operations. For example, check the database for data, if there is data, perform a database write (insert/update), if not continue without doing anything. I have written myself a promise based database API using [promise-as3](https://github.com/CodeCatalyst/promise-as3). Any database operation returns a promise that is resolved with the data of a read query, or with the Result object(s) of a write query. I do the following to nest promises and create one point of resolution or rejection for the entire 'initialize' operation.

```
public function initializeTable():Promise 
{ 
    var dfd:Deferred = new Deferred();
    select("SELECT * FROM table").then(tableDefaults).then(resolveDeferred(dfd)).otherwise(errorHandler(dfd));
    return dfd.promise;
}

public function tableDefaults(data:Array):Promise 
{
    if(!data || !data.length) 
    {
        //defaultParams is an Object of table default fields/values.
        return insert("table", defaultParams);
    } else 
    {
        var resolved:Deferred = new Deferred();
        resolved.resolve(null);
        return resolved.promise;
    }
}

public function resolveDeferred(deferred:Deferred):Function 
{
    return function resolver(value:*=null):void 
    {
        deferred.resolve(value);
    }
}

public function rejectDeferred(deferred:Deferred):Function 
{
    return function rejector(reason:*=null):void 
    {
        deferred.reject(reason);
    }
}
```

My main questions:

1. Are there any performance issues that will arise from this? Memory   leaks etc.? I've read that function variables perform poorly, but I don't see another way to nest operations so logically.
2. Would it be better to have say a global resolved instance that is created and resolved only once, but returned whenever we need an 'empty' promise?

**EDIT:**
I'm removing question 3 (Is there a better way to do this??), as it seems to be leading to opinions on the nature of promises in asynchronous programming. I meant better in the scope of promises, not asynchronicity in general. Assume you have to use this promise based API for the sake of the question.

Comment: Since you are asking for opinion here is mine, I would never do that, it's weak and untyped all over the place, when an error arise good luck finding where it comes from and where it started from (downside of callbacks).

Comment: Is there something you would recommend instead? The database API has well written error handlers which reject the database operation promise with the corresponding error (I should mention this is SQLite, so it is an SQLError object), so it would really not be too hard to determine what database call the error arose from. e.g. inserting a bad column would throw a "No such column COLUMN" error, and you would immediately know the error arose in the insert operation.

Comment: Personally I wrote my own SQLite manager that wraps up all SQLite API and provide a easy to use interface. Because of the way SQLite works errors have to happen and so it's simply faster to catch them and dispatch or not an event when that happens. I have a QueryResult class and when running queries I get a vector of that or a single instance or nothing if an error happens etc ... I make my life easier and simpler with that.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what I'm saying by promise based database API. What I have done is written an SQLite manager as you suggest, but instead of conducting asynchronous operations with events or callbacks, I do so with Deferred objects and Promises. I find this helpful to organize code. I fail to see how returning a promise is too different from returning a QueryResult. You could even return QueryResult or a vector of QueryResults in your promise! Finally creating deferred instances is akin to dispatching/listening for events... The memory imprint of promises is minimal.

Comment: So I guess you love promises and you asked a question so you could tell how much you love it to everyone answering ... good for you.

Comment: So what if I do? I'm not really asking about promises themselves, more so the technique to resolve or reject them. There is no reason to be negative about it, every programmer has their own preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't write those kind of opinion based answers, but here it's pretty important. Promises in AS3 = **THE ROOTS OF ALL EVIL** :) And I'll explain you why..

First, as BotMaster said - it's weakly typed. What this means is that you don't use AS3 properly. And the only reason this is possible is because of backwards compatibility. The true here is, that Adobe have spent thousands of times so that they can turn AS3 into strongly type OOP language. Don't stray away from that.

The second point is that Promises, at first place, are created so that poor developers can actually start doing some job in JavaScript. This is not a new design pattern or something. Actually, it has no real benefits if you know how to structure your code properly. The thing that Promises help the most, is avoiding the so called [Wall of Hell](http://callbackhell.com/). But there are other ways to fix this in a natural manner (the very very basic thing is not to write functions within functions, but on the same level, and simply check the passed result).

The **most important** here is the nature of Promises. Very few people know what they actually do behind the scenes. Because of the nature of JavaScript (and ECMA script at all), there is no real way to tell if a function completed properly or not. If you return `false` / `null` / `undefined` - they are all regular return values. The only way they could actually say "this operation failed" is by *throwing an error*. So every promisified method, can potentially throw an error. And each error **must** be handled, or otherwise your code can stop working properly. What this means, is that **every single action inside Promise is within try-catch block**! Every time you do absolutely basic stuff, you wrap it in try-catch. Even this block of yours:

```
else 
{
    var resolved:Deferred = new Deferred();
    resolved.resolve(null);
    return resolved.promise;
}
```

In a "regular" way, you would simply use `else { return null }`. But now, you create tons of objects, resolvers, rejectors, and finally - you try-catch this block.

I cannot stress more on this, but I think you are getting the point. **Try-catch is extremely slow!** I understand that this is not a big problem in such a simple case like the one I just mentioned, but imagine you are doing it more and on more heavy methods. You are just doing extremely slow operations, for what? Because you can write lame code and just enjoy it..

The last thing to say - there are **plenty** of ways to use asynchronous operations and make them work one after another. Just by googling `as3 function queue` I found a few. Not to say that the event-based system is so flexible, and there are even alternatives to it (using callbacks). You've got it all in your hands, and you turn to something that is *created because lacking proper ways to do it otherwise*.

So my sincere advise as a person worked with Flash for a decade, doing casino games in big teams, would be - **don't ever try using promises in AS3**. Good luck!

Comment: I don't really find your answer too helpful. Promises have made it much easier to structure my asynchronous code, I am going to continue using them, as I have not really seen a drop off in performance. I have revised the question to remove opinion from the answer. I am more curious about the "helper" functions which resolve or reject a deferred object, but return a function so they can be used as callbacks.

Comment: could you give more detail on how as3 being loosely typed is the "reason" promises are a bad choice in it?  AS was designed on ECMA, so I'm confused as to how a useful tool in js would not be a useful tool in AS.  The only difference between the two that you point out is Semi-Static typing, so I'm curious if you could elaborate on that

Comment: I didn't say that AS3 is loosely typed, it's right the opposite - it's strongly typed language. It's bad choice for me not to use any type at all, and have everything anonymous. Promises are useful tool for JS **only** if you don't know how to structure your code properly. **Everything** that you can do with promises you can do without. And the biggest thing I stress on is that *try-catch* is **extremely slow**. You trade eye-candy nice looking code for performance. In developer kind of view - this is nonsense.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid very nested structures in JavaScript is the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It does everything that Promises do, but without *try-catch*. Look at `series`, `parallel` and `waterfall`. Having similar functionality in AS is extremely easy to implement, while you still benefit from strong typing (like `Vector` for example). It's like using Java or C# with anonymous functions. Come on, AS3 has high-level designs such as interfaces, and we're talking about why not putting everything inside try-catch, cross fingers and pray.. :)

Comment: You mention callbacks as an alternative.  In my experience callbacks are the root of all eveil and Promises help to avoid that.

Comment: There's no silver bullet for all problems. There are means to resolve particular issues. Promises solve some, but add others. The same way callbacks do. Pick the right tools for your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
var dfd:Deferred = new Deferred();
select("SELECT * FROM table").then(tableDefaults).then(resolveDeferred(dfd)).otherwise(errorHandler(dfd));
return dfd.promise;
```

This is the [The Forgotten Promise](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) antipattern. It can instead be written as:

```
return select("SELECT * FROM table").then(tableDefaults);
```

This removes the need for the `resolveDeferred` and `rejectDeferred` functions.

```
var resolved:Deferred = new Deferred();
resolved.resolve(null);
return resolved.promise;
```

I would either extract this to another function, or use `Promise.when(null)`. A global instance wouldn't work because it would mean than the result handlers from one call can be called for a different one.